# Change type assignment for imported non-typed modules from 'any' to 'unknown'

Tags: typescript

I recently found out a bug that was caused by importing a variable from a non-typed js file into a tsx file.

Here a shortened example:

`file1.js`

```
const a = "test"
export a
```

`file2.tsx`

```
import { a } from 'file1'
const b: {firstName: string, lastName: string} = a // TS doesn't complain, bad
```

TS didn't complain of course, because `a` is inferred to *any* which is a *pas partù* for trouble, and its value can be assigned to whatever typed variables.

Is there a way to tell TS that all imported modules from a non-typed file should be inferred to *unknown* instead of *any* so that, for an assignment such as the one above, a type error would occur?